# I have around 2000 data points for multiple locations for time series forecasting. Can I apply LSTM model on it?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, lstm

I am new to machine learning and therefore, trying to figure out if my dataset is enough to run LSTM model.
I am trying to do time series forecasting on daily road traffic data. Currently, I have daily data (2012-2019) for 20 different locations. Essentially, I just have ~2800 data points for each of the location. Is that a good dataset to start with?

Any recommendations on how I can tweak the data or transform it to help with my dataset?

Please help! Thank you!!

Comment: could you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this your dataset is ~ 2800*20 examples. Now you can always run an LSTM/RNN model on this much data, but you should try to check whether they are outperforming baseline models like `Autoregressive Moving Average (ARMA)`,
`Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average (ARIMA)`.

Also, if data is in format:

```
Example_1: Day_1: x, Day_2:y, ...., Day_n: xx .etc
```

Rather than inputing whole `Day_1 ... Day_n` features to predict `Day_n+1`

You can always increase your dataset by using `Day_1` to predict `Day_2` and so on.

Check this [LINK](https://github.com/kartikey-singh/Hackathons/blob/master/Flipr%20Hackathon/Task-2.ipynb). Something I worked on which might help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I went through your code, but I had a doubt. Even after considering 2800*20 matrix, my dataset to forecast would just be from 2800 points. Please let me know if you'd like me to give more explanation.

Comment: I've tried exponential smoothing on this model (since the data has trend and seasonality) and it produces good results, but wanted to extend it further and see if machine learning methods can be applied.

Comment: If you are really constrained about data you can augment your data by adding small random errors to values.